# Azure Communication Service rewriting email urls to azurecomm.net

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

While sending emails using Azure Communication Services, the sent emails contain our company URLs which are rewritten to `azurecomm.net` URLs which is not expected behavior.

If we use a URL like, `https://api.example.com/test` it sends this exact URL but if we use a URL like, `https://example.com`, it's changing the URL to `https://action.azurecomm.net/api/...`

Would appreciate any help in the matter.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that when a URL doesn't contain a path but only the protocol and domain, it gets rewritten to the azurecomm.net?

Comment: that is correct. and according to some references I read, it mainly does it after //

Comment: The rewriting takes place when you have the "User interaction tracking" enabled. It should only apply to URLs in `<a href>`. Can you please confirm that is the case? If it happens outside of `<a href>`, can you please share the whole email template (anonymized)?

Comment: Yes, the URL is in `<a href>`
I can share the email template if that helps.

Comment: Additionally, I don't remember seeing an option in ACS to enable "User interaction tracking" so I wonder how is it enabled if so.

Comment: You can turn it on and off on the Overview tab of your Email Communication Services Domain.

Comment: yup that solves it and I understand why User interaction needs to go through azure's API however, it would be nice if the URLs can still stay the same and you guys can use some other mechanism to do user interaction maybe like routing fonts or other assets through azure links. (just a suggestion) Thanks a bunch for the help though. I'll add the answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment by @rocky, rewrite automatically happens on `<a href>` as it's used by ACS to track user interaction on the email.

To toggle user tracking, you can go to Communication Service > go to Domains (under email section) > click on the domain name (second column) > in the overview section to the right there's an option to toggle `User interaction tracking`

Hope this helps someone.